# why is my nested loop not executing inside while statement with the if statement

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, random, module, integer

**what is wrong with this code?**
why is my nested loop not executing inside while statement with the if statement
This is a stock market game
what is wrong with this code?

```
import random

amount = 0
cash = 1000
y = input("How many days would you like to play ? : ")
x = 0
move=0
y=int(y)


while x < y:
    price = int(random.randint(50 , 1000))
    print("Stock Price:" )
    print (price )
    print("Cash: ")
    print(cash)
    print("Stocks Owned: ")
    print(amount)
    print("Days Remaining: ")
    print(x)
    print("What do you want to do? 1 to buy stocks, 2 to sell stocks, 3 to skip a day.")
    move=input(": ")
#taking the input from user
    if move == 1:
        stock=int(input("how many stocks would you like to buy? : "))
        amount = (price * stock)
        cash = cash - (price * stock)
        x = +1
        print("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    elif move == 2:
        cash = cash + (amount * price)
        amount = 0
        x = x + 1
        print("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    elif move == 3:
        x = x + 1
        print("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")

print("You made " + cash + "$ in " + " days.")
print("Score: " + cash / y)
```

*why is the if statement not working *

Comment: I don't see any nested loop, but under `move == 1`, you have `x = +1` instead of `x = x + 1`. Every time you buy stocks, the days spent gets reset.

Answer (score 1):

```
move = input(": ")
```

This is where you have done the mistake. When you get the input like this, the value is considered as type "String". (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)

Use,

```
move = int(input(":"))
```

as you have done in other places like getting the input for stock

Answer (score 0):

Move needs to be an integer, but it is a string when returned by the input function, so currently none of the conditions evaluate as true. You could make the if statement work by defining move as: `move = int(input(": "))`.

```
import random

amount = 0
cash = 1000
y = int(input("How many days would you like to play ? : "))
x = 0
move = 0

while x < y:
    price = int(random.randint(50 , 1000))
    print("Stock Price:" )
    print (price )
    print("Cash: ")
    print(cash)
    print("Stocks Owned: ")
    print(amount)
    print("Days Remaining: ")
    print(x)
    print("What do you want to do? 1 to buy stocks, 2 to sell stocks, 3 to skip a day.")
    #taking the input from user
    move = int(input(": "))

    if move == 1:
        stock = int(input("how many stocks would you like to buy? : "))
        amount = (price * stock)
        cash = cash - (price * stock)
        x = x + 1
        print("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    elif move == 2:
        cash = cash + (amount * price)
        amount = 0
        x = x + 1
        print("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    elif move == 3:
        x = x + 1
        print("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")

print(f"You made ${cash} in {y} days.")
print(f"Score: {cash / y}")
```